# CodeDom compiling error (Illegal Characters at Path)

Tags: c#, codedom

I'm trying to use a C# application to create a seperate .exe, and it seems that I've come to an error.

Using the code below, I'm getting this error:

```
System.ArgumentException: Illegal characters in path.
   at System.IO.Path.GetFileName(String path)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)
   at System.IO.File.OpenRead(String path)
   at Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeGenerator.System.CodeDom.Compiler.ICodeCompiler.CompileAssemblyFromFileBatch(CompilerParameters options, String[] fileNames)
   at Program_Name.Core.BuildStub(String FileName, String mutex) in c:\Users\Tom\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Program_Name\Program_Name\Core.cs:line 45
   at Program_Name.Builder.button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Users\Tom\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Program_Name\Program_Name\Builder.cs:line 30
```

What is the cause for this? I'm using code off msdn.microsoft.com (link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/saf5ce06(v=vs.110).aspx)

My code is below:

```
public static void BuildStub(string FileName, string mutex)
{
    CSharpCodeProvider provider = new CSharpCodeProvider();
    CompilerParameters cp = new CompilerParameters();

    cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.dll");

    cp.GenerateExecutable = true;

    cp.OutputAssembly = "name.exe";

    cp.GenerateInMemory = false;
    string sourceFile = Properties.Resources.SourceCode;

    CompilerResults cr = provider.CompileAssemblyFromFile(cp, sourceFile);

    if (cr.Errors.Count > 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Errors building {0} into {1}",
                sourceFile, cr.PathToAssembly);
        foreach (CompilerError ce in cr.Errors)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", ce.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Source {0} built into {1} successfully.",
            sourceFile, cr.PathToAssembly);
    }

    // Return the results of compilation. 
    if (cr.Errors.Count > 0)
        Console.WriteLine("There were errors RIP");
}
```

The code I'm trying to build (Properties.Resources.SourceCode) is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`CompileAssemblyFromFile()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.compiler.codedomprovider.compileassemblyfromfile.aspx) expects as its second parameter a *file name*, what you want is [`CompileAssemblyFromSource()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.compiler.codedomprovider.compileassemblyfromsource.aspx).